# How to fix dpkg configure errors?

Tags: dpkg, gconf

I get the following error. How to fix it?

```
root@santanu-Compaq-Presario-C700-Notebook-PC:/home/santanu# sudo dpkg --configure gconf2
dpkg: error processing gconf2 (--configure):
package gconf2 is already installed and configured
Errors were encountered while processing:
gconf2
```

Comment: it shows that gconf2 is already installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to reconfigure an already configured package, just use `dpkg-reconfigure`, e.g.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gconf2`

`dpkg --configure` is only intended for first-time-configuration of a package, therefore the error-message.